# Tests for mprobit

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution, probit

I have a multinomial probit model with explicative variables that are also all either categorical or binary. I would like to know which are the main statistical tests that I should do before analysing the results of the model. 
Beig there no quantitative variables, I guess normality and heterocedasticity tests don't apply. What about colineality or multicolineality? 
I may specify that my sample has 100 obvervations.

Comment: 100 observations aren't much for a multinomial probit model. How many variables w/ how many levels do you have? How many outcome categories are there? How balanced are they?

Comment: explicated variable: travel destination (4 outcomes => 26 29 14 and 26 observations)). 6 Explicative variables: 4 categorical with order (7, 6, 4 and 8 levels), 1 categorical without order (4 levels) and 1 binary. It's true that it's not much. Most of the coefficients are not significative so I'm trying to delete variables

Comment: You don't have anywhere near enough data to explore all those variables. Realistically, you can include maybe 1 binary variable.

Comment: Ok, I keep the binary explicative variable. What should I test in that case?

Comment: You needn't focus on that specific variable per se. My point is you don't have enough data to meaningfully model your variables. Besides estimating the intercepts (ie the proportions in each category), you can probably expend ~1 degree of freedom. That could be a binary variable, or it could be a continuous variable (or an ordinal variable re-coded as continuous). Really, you need more data.

Comment: OK, I'll turn my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple-category response variables are hard to model / predict well.  You are fortunate to have relatively balanced data, but you still have only 100 observations total.  It of course depends on various factors, such as how big the effect are, but you don't really have enough data to model many variables.  Ordinal covariates are a tricky case: you can model them as categorical (i.e., ignore the order) or re-code them as continuous.  If you did the former, you would have 30 degrees of freedom consumed by your variables.  You simply don't have enough data for that.  My guess is you might be able to reliably model the data with intercepts (i.e., estimating the proportions in the different outcome categories) and consume one additional degree of freedom.  That means a single binary variable or a single continuous variable (or ordinal variable re-coded as continuous).

Your best bet, if possible, is to get as much more data as possible.